# Error in XML Schema Validation

Tags: soap, wsdl, schema, soapui, xsd-validation

I have a particular Java class like

```
public class JavaClass implements Serializable{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private ElementC ElementC = null;
    private ArrayList<ElementA> elementA = new ArrayList<ElementA>();
    private ArrayList<ElementB> elementB = new ArrayList<ElementB>();
```

and an XSD generated along with WSDL for the particular class, something like below.

(XSD File)

```
<xs:complexType name="JavaClass">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="ElementA" type="tns:elementA" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xs:element name="ElementB" type="tns:elementB" nillable="true" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xs:element name="ElementC" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Below is the chunk of Java code am using for schema validation.

When I debug to peek in the parse exception thrown, The message says

**One of '{elementA, elementB}' is expected**. (*I suppose the problem is in SAXParseException.*)

```
public void warning(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
        //System.out.println("In Warning() of SchemaErrorHandler");
        // Store warnings in the packet so that they can be retrieved from the endpoint        
        packet.invocationProperties.put("WARNING", e);    
    }
    public void error(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException 
    {
        count++;

        String error = e.getMessage();

        if(error.contains("cvc-enumeration-valid")){
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(error,"[");
            st.nextElement();
            StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(st.nextElement().toString(),"]");
            exceptionTypeDetails = (String) st2.nextElement();
```

Now when I trigger a SOAP request without **ElementB**(*Mandatory*) the SOAP throws an error saying "**ElementA** was not found, Excepted ElementA"(Even though ElementA is non Mandatory).

Please halp how can I debug the issue. Let me know incase of futher clarrifications needed on this question.

Comment: Could you provide more information in order to help us helping you? (Access to the real XSD File would be nice for example). Thanks!

Comment: @AlbertVilaCanela I have posted the XML as well. Please help if you find any answer. Thank you :)